# Make Outlook Task item through Excel Button

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, task

I want to make a simple program in which I can create an Outlook Task. User fills in data and clicks the create button.

I found the following code online and it should work, but it doesn't. No task is added in my Outlook, but no error is shown either. I have the feeling it somehow goes wrong with adding the recipients of the task.

Any clue why I don't get an error but, no tasks are added?

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add("I.wont.write.my.actual.address.in.this@example.com")
myRecipient.Type = olTo



 If myRecipient.Resolved Then
    With OutTask
    .Display
       .Subject = Cells(3, "I")
       .StartDate = Now
       .DueDate = Cells(2, "I")
       .Body = "Please see the attached email for a service request assigned to you."
    End With
End If
Set OutTask = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

I just can't figure it out and it's really breaking my brain at the moment. Hope someone can hint me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I  found the following code online and it should work, but it doesn't. No task is added in my Outlook, but no error is shown either. I have the feeling it somehow goes wrong with adding the recipients of the task.

*Correct - Attempt to **[resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210271(v=office.11).aspx)** the **[Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211006(v=office.11).aspx)** object `myRecipient.Resolve` against the Address Book before assuming its resolved `If myRecipient.Resolved Then` also defined variable `Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient` for `myRecipient`*

```
Option Explicit
Sub tasks()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add("0m3r@Email.com")
        myRecipient.Type = olTo
        myRecipient.Resolve

     If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        With OutTask
        .Display
           .Subject = Cells(3, "I")
           .StartDate = Now
           .DueDate = Cells(2, "I")
           .Body = "Please see the attached email."
        End With
    End If

    Set OutTask = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

*[Option Explicit Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)*

> <sub>Forces explicit declaration of all variables in a file, or allows implicit declarations of variables.</sub>

Comment: This actually is the answer. If not resolved it will not recognise the recipient and therefor not send the item

Answer (score 0):

Check this examples, run each one and see if they are usefull to you, hope one fit your needs:

```
Sub outlook_send_followup()

' High importance = 2
' Nothing = 1
' Low importance = 0

Dim OutApp As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim MyItem As Object
Set MyItem = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MyItem
            .To = "example@hotmail.com"
            .Subject = "hi, this is a task"
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "example@hotmail.com"
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML MSG FORMAT HERE>"
            .Importance = 1
            .FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
            .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
            .FlagDueBy = Now
            .Display
    End With

Set MyItem = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub create_outlook_taks()

'Const olImportanceLow = 0
'Const olImportanceNormal = 1
'Const olImportanceHigh = 2

Dim outlook_app As Object
Set outlook_app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With outlook_app.CreateItem(3)
        .Importance = 2
        .Subject = "THIS IS A TASK"
        .StartDate = Now + 5
        .DueDate = Now + 10
        .ReminderTime = Now - 3
        .Body = "HI YOU CREATED THIS TASK"
        .Display
        '.Save
    End With

Set outlook_app = Nothing

End Sub
```