# How to get body of the email from a shared folder?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code helps me to get data from my default folder in inbox but I 
want to change my folder which is a shared folder and placed in favorite folders

I already tried to change `getDefaultFolder` with `sharedDefaultFolder` but it doesn't work.

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object

Dim olFldr As Object
Dim olItms As Object
Dim olMail As Object

Set olApp = OutlookApp()
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("impMail")
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
```

Comment: What Outlook version are you using?

Comment: @Om3r Outlook 2010

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error from GetSharedDefaultFolder? Or that you cannot get to the folder anyway? Do you see the folder in Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You cannot simply change **[GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220100(v=office.11))** to **[GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220116(v=office.11))**, you have to also add  Recipient object The owner of the folder.*

*expression: **`.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient**, FolderType)`***

*Example With Email address*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim RecipientShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set RecipientShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com") 'address
        RecipientShareName.Resolve

    Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Set ShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(RecipientShareName, _
                                                 olFolderInbox) 'Inbox


    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = ShareInbox.Items

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem


    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Item.Subject '// Print Item to Immediate window
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

*Or if your using With just Name, then make sure **[recipient object is resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49268236/4539709)***

*Example with recipient Name*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim RecipientShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set RecipientShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r") 'address
        RecipientShareName.Resolve

    If Not RecipientShareName.Resolved Then
        MsgBox "Error on Recipient Object"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim ShareInbox As Outlook.Folder
        Set ShareInbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(RecipientShareName, _
                                                     olFolderInbox) 'Inbox
    End If


    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = ShareInbox.Items

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem


    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Item.Subject '// Print Item to Immediate window
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your satement " set olFldr ..." give you the correct folder?

You might check your folders with a statement like:

```
for each myO in olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders : debug.Print myO.name : next
```